# Parole - Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: arch-linux, segmentation-fault

The problem is simple: Everytime i try to start parole media player, I get the `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` error. I have tried the following, resulting in a staying error:

- Reinstalling
- Booting onto a live arch USB stick and running `e2fsck -pf` to repair the file system (someone else had the same problem and fixed it that way)

Other sound applications, e.g. audacity, still work. There also isn't a problem with pulseaudio, as it works as intended.

#### System Information:

(Just a copy-paste neofetch)

- OS: Arch Linux x86_64
- Host: N13xWU
- Kernel: 4.15.6-1-ARCH
- Uptime: 10 mins
- Packages: 1031
- Shell: bash 4.4.19
- Resolution: 1920x1080, 1920x1080
- DE: Xfce
- WM: Xfwm4
- WM Theme: Border-only
- Theme: Adwaita-dark [GTK2]
- Icons: Xenlism-Wildfire-MidNight [GTK2]
- Terminal: xfce4-terminal
- Terminal Font: Inconsolata 13
- CPU: Intel i7-8550U (8) @ 4.000GHz
- GPU: Intel Integrated Graphics
- Memory: 1568MiB / 7861MiB

#### EDIT:

The versions of parole, gst-plugins-base and gst-plugins-good are the following:

```
[alexander_schoch@Arch: ~]$ pacman -Q parole gst-plugins-base gst-plugins-good
parole 0.9.2-2
gst-plugins-base 1.12.4-1
gst-plugins-good 1.12.4-2
```

Everything should be updated to the newest version, as I update the system every day.

#### EDIT 2:

```
[root@Arch: /ubuntu/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections]$ pacman -Qm
breeze-obsidian-cursor-theme 1.0-3
cava 0.6.0-1
compiz-bcop 0.8.14-2
compiz-core 0.8.14-5
compiz-fusion-plugins-main 0.8.14-1
compiz-gtk 0.8.14-5
compizconfig-python 0.8.14-1
compton-conf 0.3.0-3
cower 17-2
discord 0.0.4-1
dpkg 1.18.24-3
dropbox 43.4.50-1
faac-git 1.29.3.r158.ga9f67bf-1
gdm-plymouth 3.26.2.1-2
gdm3setup-utils 20150507-1
glava-git r123.b4fe4b5-1
glfw-x11-git 3.2.1.r517.gf4cd470b-1
gst-fluendo-mp3 0.10.32-2
gstreamer0.10 0.10.36-17
gstreamer0.10-base 0.10.36-11
gstreamer0.10-base-plugins 0.10.36-11
gstreamer0.10-fluendo-mp3 0.10.32-2
gtk-theme-arc-solid-grey-git r728.51780e1-1
libc++ 5.0.1-1
libc++abi 5.0.1-1
libc++experimental 5.0.1-1
libcompizconfig 0.8.14-1
libgdm-plymouth 3.26.2.1-2
neofetch 3.3.0-1
neroaac 1.5.4.0-3
numix-cursor-theme-git r32.e92186d-1
pacaur 4.7.10-1
package-query 1.9-2
plymouth 0.9.3-3
pulseeffects 3.2.1-1
tiv 2015-1
trizen 1:1.43-1
vlc-git 4.0.0.r1802.g3706edb4f0-1
warmux-git e0dc503-1
webkitgtk 2.4.11-11
webkitgtk2 2.4.11-11
xfce-theme-manager 0.3.7-2
yaourt 1.9-1
```

Comment: @dsstorefile The main problem why I can't solve it myself is that I never had such an error. Ergo: define "backtrace". Do you mean gdb?

Comment: Also: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Step-by-step_debugging_guide

Comment: Paste the output of `pacman -Qm`.